# Unable to Deploy to Azure Container using GitHub Actions - Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to get app runtime OS

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, github-actions, continuous-deployment

**1. Summarize the problem**

I am trying to deploy code to an Azure App Service container from GitHub using GitHub actions. Using GitHub Actions I am able to successfully checkout my master branch, login to the azure container registry, build the container using docker, and push my docker image to the container. But I get the following error when Deploying to Azure Web app using azure/webapps-deploy@v2 and the publish profile for application authorization.

```
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: dtpdashboardContainers
    slot-name: production
    publish-profile: ***
    images: dtpdashboardcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/client:29b2d0a483f35ffd4490d75443b309f3a28c8ad9
    package: .
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to get app runtime OS
{}
```

**2. Describe what you've tried**

Of note, I am able to manually deploy via the azure portal. I can go to the Azure Portal Deployment Center for the container, select the new image which was built and passed to the Azure Container Registry and deploy. This all works as expected but I am frustratingly unable to accomplish this via GitHub actions on push.

**3. Show some code**

The build succeeds, the deploy fails with the aforementioned error. I have been struggling with this for a while now so I would greatly appreciate your help! Thanks.

```
 Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy client container app to Azure 

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - master
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-18.04'

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Login to Azure Container Registry
      uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: dtpdashboardcontainerregistry.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CONTAINERUSERNAME_1EBED267A6874BAE8C94362D3A133011 }}
        password: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CONTAINERPASSWORD_3E64C8001D134F0F87A64922FA0D562B }}

    - name: Build Container
      run: docker build -t dtpdashboardcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/client:${{ github.sha }} ./client

    - name: Push client image 
      run: docker push dtpdashboardcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/client:${{ github.sha }}

  deploy:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-18.04'
    needs: build
    environment:
       name: 'production'
       url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'dtpdashboardContainers'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_49fd57adb2104ab59b9a586e4a6e8049 }}
        images: 'dtpdashboardcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/client:${{ github.sha }}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, this was resolved by removing Access Restrictions from app.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. I had a private endpoint enabled in the "Inbound Traffic" sub-section of Networking for the App Service that was set up with an Access Restriction because we were using a virtual network. Disabling that caused my deploys to start working again.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for similar cases, no more effective content was found to solve this problem. I can only suggest you to try.

**Steps to try:**

1. Modify the ubuntu version, use runs-on:'ubuntu-latest'
2. Re-create a webapp (under a different region) for testing, and also perform a deployment

**Links I searched for, for reference:**

1. [Error Failed to get app runtime OS #95](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/95)
2. [Kudu services unavailable #1](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/Linux/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Try to restart your app service from the Azure Portal, then re-run the failed jobs in GitHub Actions.

---

This problem can have many causes. In order to narrow down the cause of your specific case I recommend turning on `debug logging` in GitHub Actions, which might reveal the underlying cause.
You can do this by:

1. Click the Re-run failed jobs button
2. Check the "enable debug logging" checkbox
   [image: screenshot]
3. Wait for the runner to fail again, but this time inspect the new debug logs.

In my case, the debug logs revealed that the Kudu App Runtime diagnostics (which are required for the deployment) were unavailable, and the server returned 503.
I inspected my app service and saw that it was in a crashed state, so I restarted it and it made the Kudu App Runtime diagnostics available again, so when I tried to run the deployment again, it worked.

Your case might reveal that the Runtime Diagnostics was unavailable due to lack of permissions (401 or 403 HTTP status), in which case [mcy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870514/16968599) might be helpful.

[image: gh actions screenshot]